# Displaying specific content based on dynamic urls?

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, next.js, routes, prisma

Basically I build page which is listing books. After clicking on particular element of the list, for example book titled „Chip War” I am dynamically redirecting to specific page with the review of each book. To generate book list and every Link href attribute corresponding to each of book I pull data from database. So my book review page url for example looks like this books/reviews/chipwar. To this moment everything works fine. Where I am stuck is displaying particular data on review pages.

I was trying to build my query to the database around useParams hook. So when I am on the page with the link books/reviews/chipwar I try to extract the last part of the link: chipwar, and use it in the query to catch and display  information about this book only (for this cause my database has this particular field, which is book title without any spaces).

This solution haven’t worked for me and I am encountering errors of all type all the way. I don’t have any idea how to make it work. What am I doing wrong here, or is there any better way to do it

I am using MongoDB with Prisma.

Comment: Hey! Just a heads up, the StackOverflow guidelines (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) suggest always including example code in your question. It's almost impossible to diagnose your issue without your code that describes the issue in detail.

Answer (score 0):

You can try redirecting to "**books/reviews/bookId(__id)**", Here the **bookId** is the **__id** of the book in MongoDB database, then you can fetch data according to id. Or you may be facing problem while getting the book name from url using useParams. Try debugging with logging. Hope this helps!